# Small air blower (12V DC motor) only buzzing

Tags: arduino

I'm trying to get my DC Brushless fan (an air blower like this one: https://iprototype.nl/products/components/overige/blower-squirrel-cage ) working.

This is my set-up: (note that the DC motor in the image is my fan)

[image]

And this is my code (nothing fancy):

```
int motorPin = 9;
void setup() { 
    Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(motorPin, OUTPUT);
}
void loop() {
  for(int i=0; i < 255; i++) {
  analogWrite(motorPin, i);
  Serial.println(analogRead(motorPin));
  delay(5); 
  }
}
```

The only thing my air blower is doing is BUZZING. A little "peeeeep" coming out of it, so there is a connection but it doesn't seem to work for some reason.

My battery i'm using is a normal Duracell 9V battery and when I hold the cables of my air blower against the + and - of my battery it works pretty well, so the voltage should be enough.

Would anyone know a solution for this?

Comment: It looks like you may have the transistor backwards.  The emitter should be connected to ground, but the way it looks in the image, it looks like the collector is connected to ground.  Can you check that the emitter is connected to ground, and that the collector is connected to the motor?

Comment: @WarreBuysse please make sure to comment on whether or not the below answer solved your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off I would be careful posting this here. There are a TON of trolls that will push you off Stack Overflow because this is an [Engineering question.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/28284/amr)

That said:

First thing I noticed that is wrong.

You are using  `analogWrite(motorPin, i);` but you clearly have it plugged into the digital pins on the Arduino. The pins that are marked A0-A5 are your analog pins.

What you want to use is `digitalWrite(pin,value)`
[Arduino Documentation](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/DigitalWrite)

Second, have you tested this with a multimeter?

I would be concerned with how much current is actually getting to your blower and if it's enough to run it. This really depends on how it is wired. I would suggest using an H-Bridge for anything motor related. You can find them REALLY cheap on sparkfun. I use one from adafruit. You can see an example of it working and how it's wired at http://anthonyrussell.info/postpage.php?name=65 If you could attach an actual photo of your setup that might be a little more useful

Comment: I needed to use digitalWrite indeed, and I was using a wrong transistor. The PN2222 instead of the KN2222. That fixed the problem. Thank you!